# Handling literal zero in unit-safe code

Tags: c++, unit-conversion

With a very few exceptions (looking at you, Fahrenheit and Celsius temperature scales), units are linear, and the value zero is simultaneously the additive identity for all units at once.

So given

```
auto speed = dimensioned(20, _meter/_second);
auto power = dimensioned(75, _watt);
```

then

```
if (speed < 6) ...
if (power > 17) ...
```

makes no more sense than

```
if (speed > power) ...
```

you should write

```
if (speed < dimensioned(6, _mile/_hour)) ...
```

However, this DOES make sense:

```
if (speed < 0)
```

because 0 m/s == 0 mph == 0 A.U./fortnight or any other units that you care to use (for velocity).  The question then is how to enable this and only this usage.

C++11 explicit operators and contextual conversion to `bool` got rid of the need of the "safe-bool" idiom.  It appears this problem can be solved with a comparable "safe-zero" idiom:

```
struct X
{
  int a;
  friend bool operator<(const X& left, const X& right) { return left.a < right.a; }
private:
  struct safe_zero_idiom;
public:
  friend bool operator<(const X& left, safe_zero_idiom*) { return left.a < 0; }
};
```

- Demo: http://ideone.com/vUxmxi

Unfortunately it seems that deployed dimension/unit libraries aren't doing this.  (This question arose because I actually wanted to test whether a `std::chrono::duration` was negative).  Is this useful?  Are there cases that would cause it to fail?  Is there any easier way to permit comparison to zero?

One suspects that instead of implementing this for individual operators, there ought to exist an implicit conversion from literal zero to unit-tagged types.

---

I do note that it allows

```
 X{1} < nullptr
```

as a valid expression :(, and unfortunately providing an inaccessible overload of type `std::nullptr_t` doesn't fix this, since the Standard says in section 4.10

> A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: For `speed < 6`, what real harm is there in letting `6` adopt the same units as `speed` implicitly?

Comment: @jxh: Besides that it would defeat the entire purpose of being unit-safe?  Forbidding any implicit association of units is pretty much universal in these libraries, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/17733452/103167

Comment: I see, it can prevent a bug in the code if the units for `speed` itself changes.

Comment: @jxh: Yes, which is especially likely in template code which may work on inputs with different units.

Comment: Awsome question. It definitely rings the bell of the universal 0 value that C++ alreay has regarding any type. before nullptr of C++11, NULL was defined to 0. and 0 is assignable to floats and double without conversion warning. 0 has a special universal meaning in C++ I wonder if this is exploitable in your case.

Comment: @v.oddou: I *am* exploiting it here, asking whether this is actually a good idea or I missed some weird case.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Do you have some answer to this today finally ?

Comment: Static analysis tools will also complaint about using 0 instead of `nullptr` for pointers.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. You convinced me pretty easily that this is useful.
2. You already pointed out a failure point, for `nullptr`. I couldn't think of anything other than that.
   My attempts at devising a mechanism to disallow `nullptr` but allow `0` all yielded complicated schemes that didn't work. Basically, since there is no way to tell C++ you want a `constexpr` function parameter, it is hard (I won't say impossible yet...) to devise a function that takes an `int` argument, but results in compile time failure if the argument value is not `0`.
3. If you are okay with allowing `nullptr`, then an easier implementation would be to use `std::nullptr_t` directly rather than a separate `safe_zero_idiom` class. (Admittedly, it is not as safe, since there is no way to access the `safe_zero_idiom` type in your implementation.)

```
struct X
{
  int a;
  friend bool operator<(const X& left, const X& right) { return left.a < right.a; }
  friend bool operator<(const X& left, std::nullptr_t) { return left.a < 0; }
};
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that.  Had another thought, but it turns out `nullptr` converts happily to function and member pointer types as well.

Comment: about point 2 : what if you make a template comparison operator, and if the deduced argument is an integral constant, you can static assert against the value 0.

Comment: @v.oddou: I tried that, it didn't work. But if you get it working, please post it.

Comment: I think you're right, because an actual function parameter cannot be a constexpr, only template parameters can be worked uppon at compile time.

Comment: I think the only feasible solution has to exploit the fact that `nullptr` **is** a `std::nullptr_t`, whereas `0` merely converts to one. Overload resolution can differentiate between the two. Furthermore, `0` converts to `T::*()`, and so does `nullptr`, but almost nothing else does. So, if both overloads exist, the first would be chosen for `nullptr` and the second only for `0`.

Comment: @MSalters: The problem is that `0` converts equally well to `nullptr_t` and any pointer type.  So it is ambiguous.  If you have a working demo I'd love to see it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If I had a solution, I would have posted it as an answer instead of a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could only come up with an obvious solution that drifts away from what you want:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>

using namespace boost::mpl;

struct X
{
    int a;

    friend bool operator<(const X& left, const X& right)
    {
        return left.a < right.a;
    }

    template< typename T >
    friend bool operator<(const X& left, T zero)
    {
        static_assert( is_same<int_<0>, T>::value, "cannot compare against arbitrary things");
        return left.a < 0;
    }
};

int_<0> unitless0;


int main()
{
    X x;

    //if (x < 3) cout << "oopsie";  // we get a build error here as excpected.

    if (x < unitless0)
        cout << "ok";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh I definitely wouldn't want that, as it inhibits implicit conversions.  Even if a slightly different literal zero were good (which with user-defined literals might not be so bad), `static_assert` is terrible and one should be using SFINAE instead.  How is the template helping here anyway, couldn't the type of the second param just be `int_<0>` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt : definitely, this is just the result of multi-mutation steps in the making of this code sample. So a hysterical raisin basically :) do not mind it. Also the int_<0> could be something like your safe_zero_type, an empty struct would do the job just perfectly. This code sample is just idiotic. But it serves the discussion.